# _id get converted from ObjectId to string in MEAN application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a MEAN stack application.

In my database, a document has a mongo ObjectId like such :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57e15b1009cb82cafafafd73"), "name" : "Hello", "artist_id" : "world", "year" : "2000" }
```

But when I load the document in my front end, the _id gets converted to a string, and my object looks like this when logged in the browser:

```
{ "_id" : "57e15b1009cb82cafafafd73", "name" : "Hello", "artist_id" : "world", "year" : "2000" }
```

What is annoying is that when I want to modify my database from my front end (update or delete an existing document), I have to convert the _id from string to ObjectId in order to target the document in my database...
So in my node application, I have to systematically massage the _id with `new ObjectId(stringId)` because the Id's sent by the browser are strings...

Obvisouly I'm missing out on something.
How can I make things more elegant ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong about `new ObjectId(stringId)`. Since there's no *ObjectId* type in JavaScript you need to use mongo's ObjectId method to cast it to one.

Comment: `ObjectId` isn't a supported type in JSON, hence the (necessary) conversion to `String`.

Comment: This is normal as mentioned by @Molda , I used spring-data mongo driver and has mapped my class id as String as in java there is no ObjectId datatype, the driver does most of the work, still it's annoying to write `new ObjectId(id)` when we query. Maybe drivers aren't as matured as we want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal to convert string as objectId using ObjectId() because when you are passing it to web it's converted as json string so it is not an objectId anymore but when you are using an objectid from a document at your server side in that case you need not convert it to objectid.

You always need objectId() constructor if your _id type is string.

Answer (score 0):

What module you use for mongodb, I think mongoose?
If you are using mongoose then you do not have to convert your _id into ObjectId, just run the query with string.

```
db.collection.find({_id: "57e15b1009cb82cafafafd73"});
```

Comment: I'm using mongodb not mongoose.

Comment: What you use to connect mongodb in node application?

Comment: let mongo = require('mongodb');

Comment: I recommend you to use mongoose module.But if you want to use this mongodb then you should read the documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.

So an obvious thing thats going to happen in a MEAN application, is that the ObjectIds of the documents will be converted to strings as they are consumed as JSON objects.
That's going to require heavy use of `new ObjectId()` when recording objects in the frontend that had their ID generated by Mongo back to the database...

Any other option than using Mongoose ? I'm very happy using the standard node mongo driver for now besides having this string conversion issue...